# Returning from the '+' to '>' prompt in command line of R Studio

Tags: r, command-line, prompt

I know the prompt changes from < to + when the command line in R expects you to complete the current command. Is there a way (say, shortcut key) to immediately terminate the command being written and revert from the '+' mode to the regular console '>'?

Comment: Hit the `Esc` key?

Comment: Do you mean, is there a way to do this without having to click on the Console and typing `Esc`? I would be interested in a shortcut for that too (shorter than having to type `Ctrl+2` and then `Esc` and then `Ctrl+1`).

Comment: It terminates my session! Is there a way to safely swap between the two prompts?

Comment: `sessionInfo()`? I think the solution will be OS-specific

Comment: In `Rstudio` \ `RGui` on windoze I can hit `Esc`. In Rterm `Ctrl+c` then `enter` does the trick.

Comment: there's really not enough detail here to answer.  If your session is terminating when you hit `Esc` or `Ctrl-C` something is really weird.

Comment: When I hit ESC, it prompts me to save my progress and then turns off the session. This happenes sometimes. Is this normal or is there something probably wrong with my R Studio?

Answer (score 17):

Press 'Esc' key will bring you back to the prompt (<). You don't need to type word 'Esc'.

Comment: I seriously doubt that 's what he meant.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using a usb keyboard that has chromatic color controls via software. It sometimes mess up the keys therefore simply do a factory reset of your keyboard via install software. Then pressing "Esc" will revert to the 
"greater than sign"

Comment: Please, type it.