# How do I run an R script from within RStudio's built-in R console?

Tags: open-source, rstudio

I'm assuming it's like Python's `import` statement, but I'd like a quick answer, since I'm in the middle of an introduction class right now.

This was the closest I got, but it didn't seem to match the question, as it shows how to run an R Script from the system CLI, not the blue RStudio `>` prompt:

[Run an R-script from command line and store results in subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928633/run-an-r-script-from-command-line-and-store-results-in-subdirectory)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Short Answer using source() function

Once you [download](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/), install, and open the RStudio, you'll see a part in the lower left with blue greater than symbols [>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057350/returning-from-the-to-prompt-in-command-line-of-r-studio).

In the part of RStudio's GUI with the blue `>`, enter the following

```
> setwd('/folder/where/the/file/is/')
> source('file_name')`
...output, if any, appears below...
```

Example:

Let's assume I have a file at `/home/myusername/prj/r/learn_r/insurance_data.r` that I want to run.

I would start up RStudio, and enter the following in the little window it has labeled **Console**:

[image: Remember, it's setwd, not setpwd]

[image: Remember the quotation marks! Don't be silly like me.]

---

### Annoyingly long answer with screenshots using source() function

Well, it turned out to be much simpler than I expected to run this from RStudio's built-in console. I was surprised that this had not already been asked about RStudio, before. If it has, I guess I'll have a burned question.

Anyway, a little trial and error showed me how to do this:

[image]

Yay, output has appeared below.

Make sure to set your working directory, first.

I did this as follows from inside RStudio 1.0.143 on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS environment:

```
setwd("~/proj/r/learn_r")
```

[image]

Next, you can enter `help(source)`, you can search for the syntax of the `source()` function, and you can just type it in to the RStudio console for a prompt:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run a specific line from the R script, put the cursor somewhere in the line and press command+enter (on other pc I think is ctrl+enter). If you want to run the whole script or some parts, select the part and command+enter.

Comment: // , Can I do this from RStudio's built in console, the one with the blue `>` prompt?

Comment: You do that at the lines of your R script and it will appear in the console with the blue >.